# duplicate symbol of a function defined in a header file

Tags: c++11, header-files

Suppose I have a header file `file_ops.hpp` that looks something like this

```
#pragma once

bool systemIsLittleEndian() {
    uint16_t x = 0x0011;
    uint8_t *half_x = (uint8_t *) &x;
    if (*half_x == 0x11)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

I initially thought it had something to do with the implementation, but as it turns out, I'll get duplicate symbols with just

```
#pragma once

bool systemIsLittleEndian() { return true; }
```

If I make it `inline`, the linker errors go away.  That's not something I want to rely on, since `inline` is a request not a guarantee.

What causes this behavior?  I'm not dealing with a scenario where I'm returning some kind of singleton.

There **are** other methods that are marked as

```
 bool MY_LIB_EXPORT someFunc();// implemented in `file_ops.cpp`
```

are these related somehow (mixed exported functions and "plain old functions")?  Clearly I can just move the implementation to `file_ops.cpp`, I'm rather intrigued as to **why** this happens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If I make it inline, the linker errors go away. That's not something I want to rely on, since inline is a request not a guarantee.

It's OK to inline the function.

Even if the object code is not inlined, the language guarantees that is will not cause linker errors or undefined behavior as long as the function is somehow not altered in different translation units.

If you `#include` the .hpp in hundreds of .cpp files, you may notice a bit of code bloat but the program is still correct.

> What causes this behavior? I'm not dealing with a scenario where I'm returning some kind of singleton.

The `#include` mechanism is a convenience for reducing the amount of code you have to manually create in multiple files with the exact content. In the end, all translation units that `#include` other files get the lines of code from the files they `#include`.

If you `#include` file_ops.hpp in, let's say, file1.cpp and file2.cpp, it's as if you have:

file1.cpp:

```
bool systemIsLittleEndian() {
    uint16_t x = 0x0011;
    uint8_t *half_x = (uint8_t *) &x;
    if (*half_x == 0x11)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

file2.cpp:

```
bool systemIsLittleEndian() {
    uint16_t x = 0x0011;
    uint8_t *half_x = (uint8_t *) &x;
    if (*half_x == 0x11)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

When you compile those two .cpp files and link them together to create an executable, the linker notices that there are two definitions of the function named `systemIsLittleEndian`. That's the source of the linker error.

**One solution without using `inline`**

One solution to your problem, without using `inline`, is:

1. Declare the function in the .hpp file.
2. Define it in the appropriate .cpp file..

file_ops.hpp:

```
bool systemIsLittleEndian(); // Just the declaration.
```

file_ops.cpp:

```
#include "file_ops.hpp"

// The definition.
bool systemIsLittleEndian() {
    uint16_t x = 0x0011;
    uint8_t *half_x = (uint8_t *) &x;
    if (*half_x == 0x11)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

**Update**

Regarding

```
 bool MY_LIB_EXPORT someFunc();// implemented in `file_ops.cpp`
```

There is lots of information on the web regarding. This is a Microsoft/Windows issue. Here are couple of starting points to learn about it.

1. [Exporting from a DLL Using __declspec(dllexport)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d.aspx)
2. [Importing into an Application Using __declspec(dllimport)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fskxacy.aspx)

Comment: Interesting, I can't believe I have never encountered this before!  There was a comment that got deleted linking [to the one definition rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition), it got a little dense but as far as I understand what you are saying here, `inline` on the (non-template) function *implemented in the header file* is **required** to ensure exactly one definition, regardless of if the compiler actually inlines it or not?

Comment: Actually there is second solution: marking function definition in header file as static. This way it becomes local to every translation unit (i.e. cpp file) that includes the header file, thus removing the duplication.

Comment: @nowaqq, indeed.

Comment: Excellent, this is all a lot clearer now!  Re: the edit about symbol visibility, I appreciate the links.  I think I've got that component down pretty well in terms of what does / does not need to be exported when, I was (incorrectly) hypothesizing that somehow if functions (A) and (B) are marked to be exported but (C) is not, it would somehow cause this.  It's worth mentioning that it is not exclusive to windows, it depends more on what the default symbol visibility of the library you are building is.  It is common to see `hidden` as the default, where necessary symbols are exported.

Comment: @sjm324, when I used to program in a UNIX environment, I never had to deal with this. At the time I started programming in MS/Windows, I had to learn about this. If there are other platforms that also use it, I am not aware of it.

Comment: `-fvisibility=hidden`.  The [CMake variable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/LANG_VISIBILITY_PRESET.html#prop_tgt:%3CLANG%3E_VISIBILITY_PRESET) in conjunction with the [generated export header](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/GenerateExportHeader.html) is where it comes in.  For example, `set(CMAKE_CXX_VISIBILITY_PRESET hidden)`. This means on both OSX and Linux, things need to be exported accordingly (else linking errors).  It's **definitely** is more common on windows.  I *think* it's also only relevant for shared libraries.  Take this with a grain of salt, I'm no expert!

Answer (score 1):

Other answers explained why this happens. Here I also found a way to overcome such error when implementing functions in one header file.

You can wrap your code inside empty namespace:

**`file_ops.hpp`**:

```cpp
#pragma once

namespace {

bool systemIsLittleEndian() {
    uint16_t x = 0x0011;
    uint8_t *half_x = (uint8_t *) &x;
    if (*half_x == 0x11)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

}
```

Now doing `#include "rel/path/to/file_ops.hpp"` compiles without dublicate symbol error.

p.s. I would recommend you not to do if/else with bool return, just do `return *half_x == 0x11`